# How to make scroll bar (-track) transparent in chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In this sample, the scroll bar is hidden by default, and while hover the `.outer`, scroll bar is visible. Then how should I make scrollbar-track background transparent in chrome? I set scrollbar and scrollbar-track transparent, but it's not work.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.outer {
  margin: 20px;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 1.6;
  width: 260px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: overlay;
}

.inner p:nth-child(1) {
  background: #ce9;
}
.inner p:nth-child(2) {
  background: #8f6;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  background: transparent;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #fc0;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.outer::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.outer:hover::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It appears that chrome does not have this functionality built in. I would suggest adding a padding to the right side of your container so that the words do not collide with the scrollbar.

Comment: And why would you think Chrome is a webkit browser?

Comment: @KeeganTeetaert sorry, I described not clear. I updated the question,  the scroll bar is hidden by default, so I don't want it to take up extra space. I just need scroll-track is not visible or its background is transparent while I hover on .outer div.

Answer (score 2):

This will hide the scrollbar and will still allow users to scroll on your page

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Give the outer div some padding on hover so the scrollbar does not cover the content

```
.outer:hover{
   padding-right: 17px;
}
```

Comment: But I need `scroll-thumb` is visible, how to hide `scroll-track` only?

Comment: Sorry you didnt specify that in you question, what exactly is happening now could you post a screenshot?

Comment: I updated the question, I just need `scroll-track` is not visible or its background is transparent while I hover on `.outer` div.

Comment: As Keegan said, this is functionality that chrome does not have.. the best way to fix this problem is to just add padding to the right of your container on hover so the scrollbar does not go on top of it

Comment: I tried it, but because the scroll bar is hidden by default, I don't want it to take up extra space. So I just ask for a better hack solution. Thanks for your time.:-)